# Modal functionalities are getting slower when developer console is opened

Tags: three.js

Here I'm facing a problem where the modal functionalities such as (PAN , ROTATE. MOUSE EVENTS) are getting lagged/stuck while using it when the debugging console is open. Where when I tried closing the console it works fine.

Another concern is why it takes me nearly 15-20 seconds to work on the functionality as explained in above issue after the modal is loaded. After the model gets loaded it takes around 15-20 seconds to use the functionality without lagging in the browser.

So what is the issue and why is it happening the way.

Comment: Can you please share an application or live example that produces the mentioned issue on your computer?

Comment: Well! I'm working on local port and it is in development stage. And so I'm facing the issue

Comment: Then please try to isolate the issue into a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/). Without the possibility of reproducing the performance problem it will be hard to provide useful feedback to your post.